# Export data to Excel in Webmatrix

Tags: sql-server, razor, export-to-excel, webmatrix

I want to be able to export the results of a query into excel by someone pressing a button that says export to excel. The following picture shows an example:
[image]

I have looked at this [WEBSITE](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/477436/Export-Gridview-Data-to-Excel-in-ASP-NET) which does what I would like to have on my website. The problem is that I have only worked in .cshtml pages and I am really unfamiliar with the process of where to put the codes on that website or what page extensions they should be. Can someone please guide me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written some articles about doing this within the Web Pages framework:

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/207/Exporting-The-Razor-WebGrid-To-Excel-Using-OleDb
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/204/Exporting-The-Razor-WebGrid-To-Excel

Comment: One question if you dont mind, I have modified the code on your page so that it brings up an excel sheet of only the rows that were queried not the whole database the problem is that when I open the excel sheet the whole page shows up, including the layout. Any help to only get the table not the rest of the page?

Comment: If it helps, I get a missing files warning with the list of css files I have on my page.

Comment: It sounds like you have not included `Layout = null;` at the top of the file that generates the Excel file. Check the `GenerateExcel.cshtml` file in the download

Comment: I am doing it in the same page, because I want the queried results (data) to be the ones from the query.

Comment: If the page generates HTML, that will be included in the output. Either move the routine to a separate page/file with Layout set to null, or try the OleDb method for creating your Excel file.